# ¿Por qué devuelve NaN cuando utilizo el metodo .filter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo este array de objetos:

```js
[
  {
    "id_operation": 4,
    "user_email": "lau@gmail.com",
    "concept": "Cobro de clase de ingles",
    "amount": "1500",
    "date": "2021-04-29T03:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "egreso",
    "category": 4,
    "state": true
  },
  {
    "id_operation": 5,
    "user_email": "good2021@gmail.com",
    "concept": "Cobro de sueldo ",
    "amount": "80000",
    "date": "2021-04-29T03:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "egreso",
    "category": 4,
    "state": true
  },
  {
    "id_operation": 7,
    "user_email": "ab2021@gmail.com",
    "concept": "Cobro de sueldo",
    "amount": "70000",
    "date": "2021-04-29T03:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "ingreso",
    "category": 4,
    "state": true
  },
  {
    "id_operation": 9,
    "user_email": "baty@gmail.com",
    "concept": "cobro de sueldo",
    "amount": "70000",
    "date": "2021-04-29T03:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "ingreso",
    "category": 4,
    "state": true
  },
]
```

lo que quiero hacer es **sumar** los **"amount"** por **"type"** (ingreso y egreso). Hice lo siguiente, pero en consola como resultado obtengo **NaN**.

```js
 const [operations, setOperations] = React.useState([]);

const getOperations = async () => {
      const data = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/operations");
      const operationsData = await data.json();
      setOperations(operationsData);

    // aca intento sumar por type Egreso
      const totalEgresos = operations.filter(item => item.type === 'egreso').reduce((count, item) => count + parseFloat(item), 0)
      console.log('Total: ' + totalEgresos);  
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas pasando el objeto entero al `parseFloat` necesitas pasar la propiedad `item.amount`

```javascript
const totalEgresos = operations.filter(item => item.type === 'egreso').reduce((count, item) => count + parseFloat(item.amount), 0)
```

Comment: Gracias @hawks ahora  funciona correctamente!